# How to read the String response from Retrofit

Tags: android, string, retrofit, response

I need to handle a functionality based on the retrofit response.

The post method has the request as json format and getting the response as Text **true**

I have tried to get this response as the following code snippet. But always I get **false** though I get **true** in postman response.

[image: Click to view the response]

```
private void callPostLoginAPI(String webServiceResponse) {
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
Call<ResponseBody> result = apiService.getPostDealer(postLoginAPI(webServiceResponse));
result.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
String postLoginResponse = null;
try {
postLoginResponse = response.body().string();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
 if (postLoginResponse != null || (!postLoginResponse.equals(""))) {
                    if (postLoginResponse.equals("true")) {
                        try {
                            if (PreferenceClass.getInstallationID(Loginpage.this) == null ||
                                    PreferenceClass.getInstallationID(Loginpage.this).equals("")) {
                                request_appInstallation_API(0);
                            } else {
                                checkAppUpdate();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Loginpage.this, "Please contact CMS Admin", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Loginpage.this, "Something went wrong... Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(Loginpage.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

As I tried the following,and I havent gotten the respective "Postman response value" .

```
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient1().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<Boolean> result = apiService.getPostDealer(postLoginAPI(webServiceResponse));
        result.enqueue(new Callback<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Boolean> call, Response<Boolean> response) {
                Log.i("Response", response.body().toString());

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        Log.i("callPostLoginAPI", response.body().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(Dealer_Loginpage.this, "returned", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Dealer_Loginpage.this, "Nothing returned", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Boolean> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(Dealer_Loginpage.this, "Nothing returned", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

**ApiClient.getClient1()** :

```
public static Retrofit getClient1() {
    if (retrofit1 == null) {
        retrofit1 = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(GlobalClass.sBase_Url).
                addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()).
                addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    }
    return retrofit1;
}
```

Comment: Try setting Call<ResponseBody> to Call<String> and the response.body() should give you a String

Comment: try this onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response)

Comment: I tried this.. But didnt work @NIKHILMAURYA

Comment: I tried this.. But didnt work @BineeshPBabu

Comment: @BineeshPBabu Yes...I tried by change the String to Boolean . But this callback method didnt call.

Comment: What error did you get when tried with Call<String>. You might need to use a custom type converter for this.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Attach this:

```
postLoginResponse.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", "");
```

After the line:

```
postLoginResponse = response.body().string();
```

and try.